# C# Disable Designer Code Execution

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I am developing an application with a multithreaded UI. The problem is I am reading multiple informations inside a timer. The timer gets enabled inside the constructor of the UI.

The problem is that the values (i.e. CPU Usage) are getting updated inside the designer-view of Visual Studio. I guess I could use the `DesignMode` property to enable the timers only if I'm not in the designer, but there could be a nicer solution to solve this problem.

Any suggestions?